# Query about Linq to Sql ordering

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out a better way of ordering the results of my sql query.

So far I have

```
List<ArticlePost> articlePosts = new List<ArticlePost>();
        IQueryable<ArticlePost> query = from ArticlePost in ArticlePostTable select ArticlePost;
        foreach (ArticlePost ArticlePost in query)
            articlePosts.Add(ArticlePost);
        articlePosts = articlePosts.OrderByDescending(ArticlePost => ArticlePost.atclID).ToList();
```

Is this a good way of sorting my list using linq or is there any way i can improve on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's wrong with the following?

```
var articlePosts = ArticlePostTable.OrderByDescending(ap => ap.actlId).ToList();
```

Comment: I never new you could do it that way. Thanks very much I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

```
var articlePosts = (
    from post in ArticlePostTable
    orderby post.atclID descending
    select post)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
List<ArticlePost> articlePosts = 
    ArticlePostTable
    .OrderByDescending(ArticlePost => ArticlePost.atclID)
    .ToList();
```